# MailMessage Question/Confusion

Tags: c#, winforms, email

Using this:

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
```

What is the difference between:

`mm.Sender = sender;` and `mm.From = from;`   ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Sender` property sets the `Sender` header. There can only be *one* email address on it, and if the `From` address has more than one email address, this header *has* to exist.

The `From` property sets the `From` header. It can have multiple email addresses.

See [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) (section 3.6.2):

> The originator fields of a message consist of the from field, the
> sender field (when applicable), and optionally the reply-to field.
> The from field consists of the field name "From" and a comma-
> separated list of one or more mailbox specifications.  If the from
> field contains more than one mailbox specification in the mailbox-
> list, then the sender field, containing the field name "Sender" and a
> single mailbox specification, MUST appear in the message.

Comment: Thank you very much for clering that up for me.

Answer (score 2):

The `Sender` property sets the value of the "Sender" email header, where the `From` property sets the value of the "From" email header.

The Sender field in an email message is meant to record the actual sender of the email.  Many ISPs will attempt to validate that the value for this field is correct.  In contrast, no validation is done on the From field.  The Sender field is not common.

Note that both of these are distinct from the "Reply-To" field, which is used to indicate where replies should be sent.  It's meant to override the From or Sender fields when replying.

Comment: Thank you very much for clering that up for me.